# how to pause a jquery while loop with conditional pause length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to pause a while loop for a certain amount of time based on a condition

```
var i = 2

while (i) {
    if (i == 2) {
        //pause loop for 5 seconds
        //execute function1();
    } else {
        //pause loop for 4 seconds
        //execute function2();
    }
}
```

How could I achieve this. 
Thank you

Comment: That makes little sense, why do you need the while loop at all, and what's the `do` supposed to do ?

Comment: "jquery while loop"? :)

Comment: There is no sleep/wait in JavaScript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var i = 2,
    method1 = function() {
        //do your thing
        start();
    },
    method2 = function() {
        //do your thing
        start();
    },
    start = function() {
        if( i && i == 2 ) {
            setTimeout(method1,5000);
        }
        else if( i ) {
            setTimeout(method2,4000);
        }
    }
;
```

You need to call the start() method at the end of the delayed methods.  This way, you avoid a huge number of setTimeout(method1,5000) being called before the 5 seconds is even up.

Comment: You beat me to it :) Here's a fiddle for what I did though, basically the same thing. http://jsfiddle.net/ubq2Lqzv/

Answer (score -1):

use the setTimeout() to achieve what you want.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: when I use timeout it pauses the execution but continues the loop all that happens istheirs 000's of functions executing killing the browser.